# Can regular SEO help improve Bing Custom Search API results?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing, bing-api

I've started using Bing [Custom Search API](https://www.customsearch.ai) and many of the top search results I get are... surprisingly old and irrelevant.

The Custom Search interface allows you to rank slices of websites higher than others and to boost some results, but it remains URL-based and doesn't go into weighting of actual page contents or metadata such as date, keywords, author and so on.

Will "classic" SEO tips such as using one `h1`, optimizing page title/description/keywords, etc. help improve result relevance?

I guess it boils down to asking *"does Bing Custom Search API use the regular Bing search engine behind the scenes?"*, but if it is more complex than that, any answer to my main problem will do.

Comment: @downvoter: stackoverflow is the Microsoft-endorsed place where the Azure Cognitive Services team and community will provide help, under the `microsoft-cognitive` tag. I have no other place to go ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Custom Search is basically indexing and ranking mechanism similar to the Bing search engine. Only difference in Bing Custom Search is restricting results to certain sites and/or controlling ranking of results. So, anything that helps in improving page quality (and hence ranking in Web Search) will also help in improving Bing Custom Search results.

This actually becomes more important as the candidate pool to select from is very small in Custom Search (or any such API) compared to the full-fledged Web Search API, which has billions of pages to select from.

Only caveat is it takes time to improve page quality and hence ranking, so until then you may have to pin/block/boost results.